# Copy ~200.000 of s3 files to new prefixes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have ~200.000 s3 files that I need to partition, and have made an Athena query to produce a target s3 key for each of the original s3 keys. I can clearly create a script out of this, but how to make the process robust/reliable?

I need to partition csv files using info inside each csv so that each file is moved to a new prefix in the same bucket. The files are mapped 1-to-1, but the new prefix depends on the data inside the file

The copy command for each would be something like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/top_prefix/file.csv s3://bucket/top_prefix/var1=X/var2=Y/file.csv
```

And I can make a single big script to copy all through Athena and bit of SQL, but I am concerned about doing this reliably so that I can be sure that all are copied across, and not have the script fail, timeout etc. Should I "just run the script"? From my machine or better to put it in an ec2 1st? These kinds of questions

This is a one-off, as the application code producing the files in s3 will start outputting directly to partitions.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotensteinI have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If each file contains data for only one partition, then you can simply move the files as you have shown. This is quite efficient because the content of the files do not need to be processed.

If, however, lines *within* the files each belong to different partitions, then you can use Amazon Athena to 'select' lines from an input table and output the lines to a destination table that resides in a different path, with partitioning configured. However, Athena does not "move" the files -- it simply reads them and then stores the output. If you were to do this for new data each time, you would need to use an `INSERT` statement to copy the new data into an existing output table, then delete the input files from S3.

Since it is one-off, and each file belongs in only one partition, I would recommend you simply "run the script". It will go slightly faster from an EC2 instance, but the data is not uploaded/downloaded -- it all stays within S3.

I often create an Excel spreadsheet with a list of input locations and output locations. I create a formula to build the `aws s3 cp <input> <output_path>` commands, copy them to a text file and execute it as a batch. Works fine!

You mention that the destination depends on the data inside the object, so it would probably work well as a Python script that would loop through each object, 'peek' inside the object to see where it belongs, then issue a `copy_object()` command to send it to the right destination. ([smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) is a great library for reading from an S3 object without having to download it first.)